# How can I set custom X-Axis label intervals?

Tags: ios, charts, ios-charts

I am using https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

**What I want to happen:**

I want the graph to have 2 x-axis ticks/labels with custom label values. My x-axis values are in date/time (I use a DateTimeFormatter based on IAxisValueFormatter). If, for example, my x-axis minimum is 1:00 pm and x-axis maximum is 4:00 pm, with label count set to 2, how can I customize what I want the label values to be? I want the values in this scenario to be **2:00 pm for label 1 and 3:00 pm for label 2**.
Is this possible with this library?

**What is Actually happening:**

It displays 2 x-axis labels on the graph with values of **label 1 = 2:40 PM** and **label 2 = 3:46**

Note:

I am adding a new datapoint every minute, so I start with an empty dataset and once per minute I add the entry to the dataset as follows:

```
...
let entry = ChartDataEntry(x: point.x, y: point.y)
lineChartDataSet?.addEntryOrdered(entry)
lineChartData?.notifyDataChanged()
view.notifyDataSetChanged()
view.reloadInputViews()
```

This is the code for setting the xAxis label count and min/max:

```
xAxis.labelCount = 2
xAxis.axisMinimum = 1553274000.0 //double value equivalent of 1 pm (timeIntervalSince1970)
xAxis.axisMaximum = 1553284800.0 //double value equivalent of 4 pm (timeIntervalSince1970)
```

Here is my axis value formatter for displaying date and time:

```
public class GraphDateTimeFormatter: NSObject, IAxisValueFormatter {
   private let dateFormatterHourMin = DateFormatter()
   private let dateFormatterMonthDay = DateFormatter()

   override init() {
       super.init()
       dateFormatterHourMin.dateFormat = "hh mm a"
       dateFormatterMonthDay.dateFormat = "MMM dd"
   }

   public func stringForValue(_ value: Double, axis: AxisBase?) -> String {
       let time = dateFormatterHourMin.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value))
       let monthDay = dateFormatterMonthDay.string(from: Date(timeIntervalSince1970: value))
       return "\(time)\n\(monthDay)"
   }
```

Comment: Could you rephrase the question and some more code? I'm not sure I understand what is the exact problem you need help with.

Comment: I want 2 labels on the graph at all times. I want to be able to customize these values. I use the IAxisValueFormatter to display in date/time, but I want to display specific time values for label 1 and label 2. How can I customize the value of label 1 and label 2 ?

Comment: are you using https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts for a chart functionality? probably that's something you want to mention in the question, (in addition to the tag you have included). Also if you can have a rough drawing about how it looks and how you want it to look, would be great too (I think I understand your question now, but still not sure how to answer)

Comment: @Lauren Share code related to `LineChartDataSet` and your `IAxisValueFormatter` implementation

Comment: @NitinAlabur yes I am using the Charts library.

Comment: @staticVoidMan I just updated my question with that information, let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Update the label count and set a custom granularity to a duodecimal multiple because time is counted in a base-12 system but the chart follows the base-10 system by default.

Try this:

```
xAxis.labelCount = 4
xAxis.granularity = 3600
```

NOTES:

- `3600` is basically `60*60`, i.e. the number of seconds in an hour

  - As per your given range of 1pm - 4pm, you want to show 2pm and 3pm labels, which are at 1 hour intervals
- `labelCount` affects `granularity`

  - We need to keep that at 4 because if `labelCount` is kept at 2 then minimum `granularity` would have to be >= 5400, i.e. interval of 1.5hours giving 1pm, 2:30pm, 4:00pm, which is not as per your expectations

    - Why `5400`? because `1553284800 - 1553274000 = 10800` and `10800/2 = 5400`